# why the validation accuracy (or training accuracy) is not exactly matched with the number of dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

I'm currently using Keras to training ResNet model with dog and cat dataset.
For example, if I have 4000 training sets, then I think the training accuracy should be 1/4000 or 0 or the multiples of 1/4000.
but the accuracy shown in the prompt is not multiples of 1/4000 and 0.
how does this happen?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwvPv.jpg)

Comment: Accuracy is measured between 0 -100 only so if you give 1000 training sets means the library covert that sets to percentage.

Comment: acturally the accuracy I can see in the prompt screen is between 0 and 1.

Comment: the 1 is 100percentge 0 is 0 percentage 0.5 is 50%. all converted by library

Comment: Can you share some examples of this phenomena? It could juts be floating point imprecision or just rounding for display, as keras shows 3 significant digits only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, but I think the problem is related to the fact your lass is nan and the accuracy is 1. I will recommend you to check your hyperparameters like the "lass function" or the "batch size".

In any case, good luck!